# kivy object property is showing float object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

i am trying to make an animation with clock in kivy,when i execute the function with the help of button it works good but when i schedule the function in clock it throws an error.

my python code is

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
login=Builder.load_file('login.kv')
class Login(BoxLayout):
    image=ObjectProperty(None)
    def press(self):
        anim=Animation(size_hint=(.3,.3))
        anim &=Animation(pos_hint={'center_x':.5,'center_y':.8})
        anim.start(self.image)
    Clock.schedule_once(press)
class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return Login()
if __name__=="__main__":
    Main().run()
```

my kivy file is:

```
<Login>:
image:img
Image:
    id:img
    source:'22.png' 
    pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
```

while i execute the program it throws the following error:

**anim.start(self.image)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'image'**

Comment: what is img????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code `Clock.schedule_once(press)` is outside any method in the `Login` class, so it gets executed when the class is loaded, before the `image` property is assigned. So, the solution is to insure that `press()` is not called until the `Login` class is ready. You can do this by moving the `Clock.schedule_once()` call into the `build()` method of the `App`.

```
class Login(BoxLayout):
    image=ObjectProperty(None)

    def press(self, dt):
        anim=Animation(size_hint=(.3,.3))
        anim &=Animation(pos_hint={'center_x':.5,'center_y':.8})
        anim.start(self.image)


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        login = Login()
        Clock.schedule_once(login.press)
        return login
```